# Calculating which child # an element is

Tags: javascript, jquery, numbers, element

So I have several slides on a page and a menuitem for each of them.
If menuitem #1 is clicked, I want to go to slide #1 and so on.
No problem so far, but I don't want to hardcode it for each item.

Is there a way to calculate which # child element got clicked? (preferably jQuery)

```
<nav id="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Hello</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">World</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Blaa</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: How does your handler look like?

Comment: take a look at `index()` method http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: looks like index() is exactly what i was searching for. thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method:

```
$('#mainNav a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
    return false;
});
```

Or if the `<a>` may be arbitrarily nested, you might use something like this:

```
$('#mainNav a').click(function() {
    alert($(this).closest('#mainNav > ul > li').index());
    return false;
});
```

[**demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/8rdvD/)

Comment: index() in combination with parent() is exactly what solved the problem. thanks mate!

Comment: @MichaelMikowski That's a good suggestion. I've incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Since you also tagged plain old [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), I'll give you a solution for that...

You could make use of [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Childnode.previousElementSibling) like so ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/WDZC9/2/)):

```
function getElementIndex(elem) {
    var i = 0;
    while (elem = elem.previousElementSibling) i++;
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will make your code fully dynamic.

```
<nav id="mainNav">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav">Hello</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav">World</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav">Blaa</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var navs = $('.nav');
        $.each(navs,function(index,value){
            $(navs[i]).attr('data-index',i);
            }
        $('.nav').click(function(){
            var nav_index = $(this).attr('data-index');
            //Do something with nav_index here
         });
});
</script>
```